# Mongodb 1to1 relation among subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a huge collection where each document has subdocuments that have relations among them. My schema looks like this:

```js
{
    userName: "user44",
    userID: "44",
    posts : [
        ...
        {
            title : "post1",
            id : "123"
            ...
        },
        {
            title : "post2",
            id : "124"
            ...
        },
        ...
    ],
    comments: [
        ...
        {
            id: 1910,
            postId : "123",
            title : "comment1",
            comment : "some comment",
            user: "user13"
        },
        {
            id: 1911,
            postId : "124",
            title : "comment2",
            comment : "some comment",
            user: "user22"
        },
        ...
    ], 
    commentUpvotes: [
        ...
        {
            id : 12,
            commentId : "1910",
            upvotedBy: "user91"
        },
        {
            id: 13,
            commentId : "1910",
            upvotedBy: "user92"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Although this has nothing to do with my database, original schema is exactly as above. So, this example above is a user collection, where I store `posts` of the user; `comments` that made to the posts by other users, `commentUpvotes` to store information about who upvoted. Don't think about the logic of its design, and don't please suggest any other schema.

Question: `db.users.find({"commentUpvotes.id" : 12})`  should return this collection, but only with the comment(1910) and post(123) that this upvote made to. I solved it with $unwinding which caused performance problems. Therefore please suggest to solve it without unwinding. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the "indentation" I am using in the listing, this may actually look longer than what you are doing, but really it isn't.

This is a another really good example of using [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) as available to MongoDB 2.6 and greater. There is still some use of [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), but the arrays being "unwound" actually only ever have **one** element in them. So please forgive my [*"Highlander"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander_%28film%29) references which I could not resist :)

```js
db.users.aggregate([

    // Match your document or documents
    { "$match": {
        "commentUpvotes.id": 12
    }},

    // Get the one "up-votes" entry that matches
    { "$project": {
        "posts": 1,
        "comments": 1,
        "commentUpVotes": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { 
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$commentUpvotes",
                        "as": "el",
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$$el.id", 12 ] },
                                "$$el",
                                false
                            ]
                        }  
                    }
                },
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }},

    // There is only one!
    { "$unwind": "$commentUpVotes" },

    // Get the one comments entry that matches
    { "$project": {
        "posts": 1,
        "comments": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { 
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$comments",
                        "as": "el",
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": [
                                { 
                                    "$eq": [ 
                                        { "$substr": [ "$$el.id", 0, 4 ] }, 
                                        "$commentUpVotes.commentId"
                                    ] 
                                },
                                "$$el",
                                false
                            ]
                        }  
                    }
                },
                [false]
            ]
        },
        "commentUpVotes": 1
    }},

    // And there is only one!
    { "$unwind": "$comments" },

    // Get the one post that matches
    { "$project": { 
        "posts": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { 
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$posts",
                        "as": "el",
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": [
                                { 
                                    "$eq": [ 
                                        "$$el.id", 
                                        "$comments.postId"
                                    ] 
                                },
                                "$$el",
                                false
                            ]
                        }  
                    }
                },
                [false]
            ]
        },
        "comments": 1,
        "commentUpVotes": 1
    }},

    // Optionally group back to arrays. There can be only one!
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "posts": { "$first": "$posts" },
        "comments": { "$push": "$comments" },
        "commentUpVotes": { "$push": "$commentUpVotes" }
    }}

])
```

So the end result would be:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("539065d3cd0f2aac5f55778e"),
    "posts" : [
            {
                    "title" : "post1",
                    "id" : "123"
            }
    ],
    "comments" : [
            {
                    "id" : 1910,
                    "postId" : "123",
                    "title" : "comment1",
                    "comment" : "some comment",
                    "user" : "user13"
            }
    ],
    "commentUpVotes" : [
            {
                    "id" : 12,
                    "commentId" : "1910",
                    "upvotedBy" : "user91"
            }
    ]
}
```

I know you asked for "no schema changes", but not really a schema change to say it is a good idea to keep your `id` values here of a consistent type. Currently you are mixing Integers and strings in this process ( I hope it's just an example ) which is not a good idea.

Thus there is some "limited casting" that actually is available employed here using [**`$substr`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/), however your actual solution may vary in how to really do this. I strongly suggest fixing the data if it really does need fixing.

At any rate, a pretty cool usage for [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)

Comment: hey Neil, thanks again, but isn't really any hope without using `$unwind`? It is killing my app because of the large arrays.. Imagine having a document of 1.5MB, and when you unwind it will be ~1MB x [array size] which will be like GB... haven't checked your `$map` yet

Comment: oh I see, you unwind the `$project` result, will check asap :)

do you think that might be an easy way with `$redact`?

Comment: @anvarik Still thinking of a good usage case for `$redact` other than the existing documentation samples. It's kind of a "field removal" method by nature, so does not really apply here. As you already "get" even with `$unwind` this is only ever (by expectancy) "unwinding" **one** item that comes out of the `$project` at each stage. So there is minimal overhead with large arrays, since they were already filtered. Still would be nice if I could see a way to "nest" this as a single stage.

Comment: I think you can replace some of `$project` + `$map` + `$setdifference` combinations with a simple `$redact` + `$cond` up there. Like first one, you can just type: `{ $redact: {$cond: { if: { $or : [{ $eq: ["$commentUpVotes",12] }, { $not : "$commentUpVotes" }]},             then: "$$DESCEND",
else: "$$PRUNE"
}
}
}` which gave me the same result

Comment: the problem above is that I won't always query for a field like `12`, it might be a field which is present in 100 subdocuments, and in this case `$unwind` will cause me problems...

Comment: @anvarik It's not really a problem though I may have oversimplified with the **one** result. But the general pattern, with the exception of the initial stage is `$unwind` `$project` `$group`. I'm only doing a `$group` once for the singular result but the general solution is as mentioned "rinse and repeat". You really need to be more specific an "clear" in your questions. You have an exact answer to the question you actually asked. I think you have good questions to ask, but you cannot hide your real intentions like this. Questions are not meant to answered in pages of comments.

Comment: yeah sorry, I didn't want to complicate the question, so just asked the simplified version. But as the query might return several results, shall I go for a new question?

Comment: @anvarik Maybe. But I think I just answered you in the comment above. The other point there was to be exact and specific. Abstract questions do get abstract answers. I think I did answer this one.

Comment: fair enough, you are right I did not give enough input and according to the question your answer perfectly works. I accept that. and if you are interested here is my post-question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063065/mongodb-many-to-many-relations-among-subdocuments